# Android app gets opened from links sent in email

Tags: android, deep-linking

Our users get emails from time to time to e.g. change their password. When they click the link, I would like to have them sent to our website, but our Android app gets opened.

The link e.g. is `https://www.ourdomain.com/change-password/{random-string}`.

We do have deep links enabled in our app, but they are configured the following way:

```
            <intent-filter android:label="...">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="customhost"
                android:pathPrefix="/"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="www.ourdomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/somethingelse"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="www.ourdomain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/againsomethingelse"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="someothercustomhost"
                android:scheme="https" />

            <data
                android:host="andagainacustomhost"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So the `change-password` part doesn't fit in any of that configurations, what could be the reason our app gets opened nevertheless?

**EDIT**

it seems as if the problem is the first `data`-tag; if I comment that out, it behaves as expected (i.e. `https://www.ourdomain.com/change-password/1234` is not handled by the app). I don't know why as `customhost` is a complete different word from `www.ourdomain.com`...

Comment: It seems like you have changed the links before posting. Which makes it a bit confusing. But this seems right. This link shouldn't be open by app. Can you recheck your question. ? Are you posting the links correctly?

Comment: yes; `www.ourdomain.com` is a german url, the `customhost`-stuff is something completely different from the url, the `change-password`-thing is 1:1 right.

Comment: could there be other reasons/configurations causing the app to listen to that domain?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276617/android-deep-links-not-following-path-prefix

Tested with answer and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to separate it into different `<intent-filter>` components, because with one `<intent-filter>` application can get confused, even if it is written correctly.

```
<intent-filter android:label="...">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />           

    <data android:host="www.ourdomain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/somethingelse"
        android:scheme="https" />

    <data android:host="www.ourdomain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/againsomethingelse"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:label="...">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="customhost"
        android:pathPrefix="/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:label="...">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="someothercustomhost"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:label="...">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="andagainacustomhost"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```